# center table within div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table within a div using the span12 class from twitter bootstrap which is contained within a row class div all surrounded by a footer tag as follows:

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td> <!-- Contact Us -->
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td><b>Contact Us</b></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td>Tel: 01234 567897</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td>E-mail: info@email.com</td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>

                <td> <!-- Useful Links -->
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td><b>Useful Links</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">Contact Us</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">About Us</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">Copyright Information</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>

                <td> <!-- Social -->
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td><b>Connect With Us</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">Facebook</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">Twitter</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">Google Plus</a></td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

I have the following CSS applied:

```
/* Table Style */

    .footer table {
        table-layout:fixed;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 100%
    }

    .footer td b {
        vertical-align:top;
        color: #ccc2a0;
    }

    .footer td {
        vertical-align:top;
        color: #a8a8a8;
    }
```

I have tried to get the space between the left side of the footer and the first table data to be the same as the space between the right side of the footer and the last table data however it always has a bigger gap on the right side.

Can anyone see a problem with the CSS I am using?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the code for trying to achieve this using divs:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:red;">
      <div class="span12" style="background-color:orange;">
        <div class="span4" id="leftFooter">

        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="middleFooter">

        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="rightFooter">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

The CSS simply colours the boxes so I can see what is going on and adds some height to the divs.[image: div layout problem]

The grey box is the footer div, the red box is the row and the orange box is the span12. The rest are the 3 content divs of span4. Not sure why they don't stay on the same row.

Comment: can you give jsfiddle or live link?

Comment: which browser are you using?  I don't see that problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/3qKKc/, neither in firefox nor in chrome.  I've added border to the table and the `footer` div.  It could be that you are just concerned about the gap due to less text on the right most table?

Comment: If you give your table a fixed width, your current code works as you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mPwrL/

Answer (score 1):

I changed some of it and stripped all styling out (sorry), but your spacing should be fixed horizontally. You can apply whatever else you want styling wise. Also, I got rid of all the embedded tables because it was so cumbersome...I can adjust the vertical spacing if you want, but I just threw this together to give you an idea for horizontal spacing.

http://jsfiddle.net/YYZwY/1/

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <table>
    <td>
                <div id="ContactUS" class="information">Contact Us</div>
                <div id="Telephone" class="information">Tel: 01234 567897 </div>
                <div id="email" class="information">Email: info@email.com</div>
    </td>
    <td>
                 <div class="links">Useful Links</div>
                 <div class="links"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
                 <div class="links"><a href="#">About Us</a></div>
                 <div class="links"><a href="#">Copyright Information</a></div>
                 <div class="links"><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></div>
    </td>
    <td>
                 <div class="connect"><b>Connect With Us</b></div>
                 <div class="connect"><a href="#">Facebook</a></div>
                 <div class="connect"><a href="#">Twitter</a></div>
                 <div class="connect"><a href="#">Google Plus</a></div>
    </td>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.links {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.connect {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.information {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: why use table at all. You removed most of it and i agree with its removal, it should not be used for layout

Comment: Good point. I was going to completely do away with the table but since he had a lot of tables first I didn't know if he really wanted tables or just didn't know another way..so I went with the happy medium. But agreed, no table is the way to go.

Comment: Hi I am trying to do it with divs now since you said that tables should not be used. I have attached a screenshot and the code for what I have got now. The problem is that if I use 3 span4 divs the last one goes onto a new line.

Comment: If you still want this done with divs, I'll see what I can whip up this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.span12 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This solution works if we don't mind the text alignment.

Result [CodePen] : http://codepen.io/loxaxs/pen/kilLG

---

A different solution:

CSS:

```
.span12 {
  padding-left: 15%;
}
```

Result [CodePen] : http://codepen.io/loxaxs/pen/izIHq